# Socat, NetCat and/or Python program don't see packets, but wireshark does

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, networking, udp

Device A is a windows machine that runs a simple python nic state checker that sends it to Device B that has Ubuntu 20.04 and a UDP listener script. I have tested this exact setup, down to installation mediums, on 5 machines with exactly same hardware specs, and on 4 of them everything is working as intended, but the outlier has a problem receiving packets: neither `nc -lup <port>` nor `socat - udp-l:<port>,reuseaddr,fork` works, not to mention the python script, but wireshark gets the packets without any issues. Here's the scripts' code, i have no idea what else to do with all of this, i've already disabled ufw and set nic broadcasts to 192.168.255.255, didn't help.

tsend.py:

```
    import socket, psutil
from time import sleep 
 

def getst(nic):
    stat = psutil.net_if_stats()
    #print (stat[nic].isup)
    if stat[nic].isup==True:
        return 'Up and ok\n'
    else:
        return 'Down, bad\n'
    
    
    
def main():
    UDP_IP = "192.168.100.10"
    UDP_PORT = 2275
    count=0
    exstate="bababooey"
    state = bytes(getst('Ethernet'), 'utf-8')
    while True:
        count+=1
        exstate = state
        state = bytes(getst('Ethernet'), 'utf-8')
        if (exstate != state) or (count >= 3): 
            count=0
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            sock.bind(("192.168.100.20", 0))
            #print (state)
            sock.sendto(state, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
            sleep(1)
            sock.sendto(state, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
            sleep(1)
            sock.sendto(state, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
            sock.close()
        sleep(10) 
main()
```

trecv.py:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import argparse
import cgi
import socket
import json
import threading
import requests
import re
import time
from datetime import datetime
import sys
from urllib import parse
import signal
    
###########----Globals----###########

    ServerIP="1.1.1.1"
    ServerPort=1234
    ServerThread=""


##########----/Globals----###########

class HTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        if re.search('/api/set/*', self.path):
            ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.get('content-type'))
            if ctype == 'application/json':
                length = int(self.headers.get('content-length'))
                rfile_str = self.rfile.read(length).decode('utf8')
                data = parse.parse_qs(rfile_str, keep_blank_values=1)
                record_id = self.path.split('/')[-1]
                LocalData.records[record_id] = data
                log("Server: setstatus %s: %s " % (record_id, data)+datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3])
                # HTTP 200: ok
                self.send_response(200)
            else:
                # HTTP 400: bad request
                log("Server: empty POST; ERR400"+datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3])
                self.send_response(400, "Bad Request: must give data")
        else:
            # HTTP 403: forbidden
            self.send_response(403)

        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        if re.search('/api/shutdown', self.path):
            # Must shutdown in another thread or we'll hang
            def kill_me_please():
                self.server.shutdown()
            # Send out a 200 before we go
            self.send_response(200) #was after the next line
            threading.Thread(target=kill_me_please).start()

        elif re.search('/api/get/*', self.path):
            record_id = self.path.split('/')[-1]
            if record_id in LocalData.records:
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                self.end_headers()
                # Return json, even though it came in as POST URL params
                data = json.dumps(LocalData.records[record_id])
                print("getstatus %s: %s" % (record_id, data))
                self.wfile.write(data.encode('utf8'))
            else:
                self.send_response(404, 'Not Found: record does not exist')
        else:
            self.send_response(403)
        log("Server: GET:"+datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3])
        self.end_headers()

def Quits(reason="KeyboardInterrupt"):
    r=requests.get("http://"+ServerIP+':'+str(ServerPort)+'/api/shutdown')
    log(reason+"; exiting: "+datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3])
    exit(1)
        
def log(msg="-----"+datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]+"-----"):
    f=open("/var/log/TServer.log", "a")
    f.write(msg+'\n')
    f.close()
    
def UDPListener(sock):
        global ServerIP, ServerPort
        msg=''
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
        url = "http://"+ServerIP+":"+str(ServerPort)+"/api/set/txlink"
        while ServerThread.is_alive():
            data, addr = sock.recvfrom(96)
            data = data.decode("utf-8")
            if data == "Up and ok":
                msg='state=0'
            elif data == "Down, bad":
                msg="state=1"
         r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=msg)
         print("updated: "+datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3])
         sock.close()
        
def main():
    global ServerIP, ServerPort, ServerThread
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.default_int_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal.default_int_handler)
            
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='TServer Process')
    parser.add_argument('ip', help='HTTP Server IP')
    parser.add_argument('port', type=int, help='Listening port for HTTP Server')
    parser.add_argument('Tx_ip', help='TX iface IP')
    parser.add_argument('Tx_port', type=int, help='TX connection port')
    args = parser.parse_args()
            
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
    sock.bind((args.Tx_ip, args.Tx_port))
            
    ServerIP=args.ip
    ServerPort=args.port
    ServerThread=threading.Thread(target=run_srv) 
    ReceiverThread=threading.Thread(target=UDPListener, args=[sock,]) 
    try:
        ServerThread.start()
        ReceiverThread.start()
        ServerThread.join()
        ReceiverThread.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sock.close()
        Quits()
    except RuntimeError:
        sock.close()
        Quits("RuntimeError")
    except OSError:
        sock.close()
        Quits("OSError")
    sock.close()
        
main()
```

Comment: You are having a problem receiving on a socket, but don't show how you open and configure the socket.  Please post a [mre]

Comment: Here it goes, @stark, any constructive criticism is welcome, as i'm new to asking on SO.

Comment: wireshark and tcpdump get the packets before they are processed by the local firewall (iptables, ufw), while nc, socat ... only get the packets after the firewall. Thus if the firewall on the system blocks the connection then you still see these in wireshark but don't get these in the listener program.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i have turned ufw off via `sudo ufw disable` and don't know of any other firewall that could be there; UPD: `iptables -S` shows `-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT`